# How to override WPF Checkbox Background Color

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, wpf-controls

I am using this xaml code to override the check box's background color  on my application.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}"              
        BasedOn="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Orange" />           
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="Yellow" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize"
                Value="30" />
  </Style>
```

In CheckBoxStyle, There is a control template for Checkbox, in that background color of checkbox is blue. I need to override this with Orange. But the above code was not working. Can anyone suggest me solution for this?

In control template background color - blue. I need to override this with orange.

Comment: Please include the template you are using for your checkbox in your question.

Comment: If you did not set TemplateBinding in the ContentTemplate, It would be easier to rewrite the copy of the template, then attempting to access and change the property of it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's blue is because there is a trigger inside the CheckBox default's template named "IsMouseOver" and it's changing it to blue every time you hover the mouse over the CheckBox, you will need to alter the default CheckBox template.

Step 1: Right-click on your CheckBox and pick "Edit Template\Edit a Copy..."

[image]

Step 2: Name your new style.

[image]

Step 3: Under ControlTemplate.Triggers look for IsMouseOver trigger and set it's value to Orange.

```
     <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="OptionMarkFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" StrokeDashArray="1 2" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFF3F9FF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF5593FF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFD9ECFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFBCBCBC"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="checkBoxBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <Grid x:Name="markGrid">
                                <Path x:Name="optionMark" Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z " Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="1" Opacity="0" Stretch="None"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="indeterminateMark" Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="2" Opacity="0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,-1,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="Orange"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Step 4: When you hover your mouse over this should be the result:

[image]